# Could the 1864 US presidential election have been postponed?

Tags: united-states, american-civil-war, election, abraham-lincoln

[This article](http://www.historynet.com/decision-1864-facts-about-the-election-of-1864.htm) on HistoryNet makes the following observation about the 1864 election:

> The 1864 race for the White House was the United States’ first presidential election during wartime. ***Proposals to postpone the election until the war ended gained little serious consideration***.

(my emphasis)

The suggestion that some aides urged Lincoln to suspend the election is also mentioned in [this article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/world/americas/3885663.stm) from BBC News.

Now, it seems that the proposals to postpone the election met little support, and Lincoln rejected them. However, if Lincoln and enough other senior politicians had wanted the election delayed, would that have been possible without a constitutional amendment?

---

Would the legal feasibility of such a postponement in 2020 be any different from the 1864 case?  (Note: [A recent poll](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/poll-majority-of-gop-would-back-2020-election-delay-if-trump-proposed-it/) showed many Republican voters would favour postponing the 2020 election if large-scale voter fraud were a concern. )

Comment: This is a good question, but a better fit for Politics SE.

Comment: @TomAu I considered that but really wanted to explore the 1864 situation for precedent and context, and I think a 2020-only question on politics.se might have overlooked this 1864 parallel.

Comment: The other reason it is a better fit for Politics SE is because it is a "counterfactual," otherwise known as a "what if" question, that makes it off topic here. Based on my own experience with Politics SE. it's far better accepted over there.

Comment: @TomAu How is it counterfactual? The question is not "What would have happened if ...?". It is "Would it have been possible?" That is a matter of fact, and can be answered with historical evidence.

Comment: @sempaiscuba:  OK, I feel the wording pushes the the question toward counterfactual. Perhaps a more historical wording is something like, "what were the relevant legal mechanisms in place in 1864... ?"(past tense) than "would it have been possible...?" (subjunctive past). Also "many Republican voters "would" favour postponing the 2020 election... " future and subjunctive.

Comment: @TomAu Yes, an alternative wording might have been better for the first question, but the second element isn't part of either question being asked her (although a link to the poll would have been nice!). The second question is also a factual one ("Would it be any different now than 1864?") and, as it happens, also answered by the answer to the first question. The comments aren't really the place for an extended discussion, but I'm happy to continue in chat?

Comment: @sempaiscuba I've added a link about that poll.

Comment: "Such proposals met little support..." -  exactly what were these proposals and by whom were they made?

Comment: @SteveBird Some Lincoln aides; see http://www.historynet.com/decision-1864-facts-about-the-election-of-1864.htm and http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/americas/3885663.stm

Comment: @J.G. I've moved the links about the background to the suggested postponement into the question, rather than having them in the comments. Feel free to roll-back if that's not OK. :)

Comment: Recommend a comments purge - I believe that many of the comments refer to a prior version of the question, and the relevant citations from comments have been migrated into the question.   I believe the question now refers to the plausibility of a historical event, which I believe is in scope.  There is an answer to the question (and I believe questions with answers should generally not be closed).  The material about the 2020 election is mentioned merely as a curiosity.  My recommendation is purge comments and re-open.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace even so, this question is more about politics and law than history (especially since by the answer given, legal situation ot this matter haven't changed since 1864). I'm voting to reopen, but it would be more in place on politics stack.

Comment: It was NOT the United States’ first presidential election during wartime - the first was in 1812, during the war War of 1812 (1812-1815).

Answer (score 5):

[Article 2 of the United States Constitution](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/articleii) states that:

> The executive power shall be vested in a President of the United
>   States of America. He shall hold his office during the term of four
>   years.

So yes, it would indeed have required a constitutional amendment prior to the 1864 election for the President's term-of-office to be extended beyond four years.

---

This would not have been entirely without precedent. The government had previously shown that it was willing to amend the Constitution to address unanticipated problems. For example, the [Twelfth Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelfth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) was passed in 1804 to address problems that had arisen with the original procedure contained in [Article II, Section 1, Clause 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Two_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Clause_3:_Electors) of the Constitution during the Presidential elections of 1796 and 1800.

---

As you observed in the question, Lincoln rejected the suggestion from his advisers that Article 2 of the Constitution should be amended. It has not been amended since Lincoln's time, so any future proposal to extend the President's term-of-office would also require a constitutional amendment.

Comment: From reading the amendment's text it appears to affect the timing of the Electoral College's ruling, but not of the people's votes.

Comment: @J.G. Yes. The amendment is to section 3 of Article 2 of the Constitution. The limit to the President's term is set out in section 1. The amendment simply illustrates that Article 2 can be amended if it is considered necessary.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Sure but the chances of a constitutional amendment being OKayed by the necessary number of states within 3.5 years is essentially zero.

Comment: Today, yes, but amendments have been passed that quickly in the past.  For instance, the 26th amendment took less than four months.

Comment: @Steven Burnap: But the 26th Amendment was non-controversial.  Given the current approval ratings of the current holder of the office, I would say that not only is there no chance of passing an amendment that would keep him in office, even trying to do so would ensure that the officeholders voting for it would not be in office much longer.

Comment: Right, no chance today, but we're talking about 1864, and also generally.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, but the question is about the _legal_ feasibility, not the _political_ feasibility.

Comment: Which, and how many of the states would have been required to approve an amendment? IIRC Lincoln made a point of not considering the Confederacy to be a distinct legal entity, and that those states were in fact still part of the U.S. This implies that those states would have had to be involved in the amendment process.

Comment: @mickeyf Well, quite. For all we know, that might even have been a factor in Lincoln's reasoning when he rejected the proposal.